# phpMyadminにアクセスできない（mysqli 拡張がありません。）

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

こんにちは。現在、PHPを勉強中です。（初心者）
昨日、phpMyadminにアクセスできない件で質問をしたのですが、現在エラー状況が変わっているため、こちらに新たに質問させていただきます。(古いほうの投稿は削除いたしました）
2日前から取り組んでいるのですがいまだに解決できておらず、、どうか知恵をお貸しいただければ幸いです。

以下質問です。

**エラー内容**
phpMyadmin(http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/)にアクセスすると、
`phpMyAdminエラー　mysqli拡張がありません。PHPの設定をチェックしてみてください。詳しくはa@doc/html/faq/mysql@documentation]ドキュメンテーションを参照してください`というエラーになってしまいます。

Chrome使用
●PHP7.4.10
●XAMPP Protcol　Panel v3.2.4　（Apache/MySQL スタートは可能)
●phpMyadminにアクセスしたく、phpmyadmin5.0.3 を昨夜[こちらのサイト](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/)からダウンロードしました

**補足情報**
　＊2日前、XAMPPのApacheが動作しなかったので、下記を行いました。（現在はApacheスタートできるようになりました）
　　・Localhostを80→8080に変更
　　・Firewallの受信設定にポート8080を追加
　　・XAMPPコントロールパネル右上のConfigからポートを8080、4433に変更
　　・ただ、直し方で試行錯誤していた際に、はっきりと思い出せないのですが、コマンド上に「指示が重複しているので無視します」といったようなエラーが出ており、php.iniの最後尾に記入していた"PHPIniDir "C:/php7"を消しました。そして現在はApacheは動きます。が、消したことが原因か、phpinfo()のphp.iniのPathが"no value"となってしまっております。ただ"PHPIniDir "C:/php7"を再度php.ini内に記入すると、またApacheがstartできなくなってしまいます・・。
　＊phpinfo()の内容はこちらです　[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
　＊php.iniは　C:\php7　にあります。
　＊php.iniの;extension=php.mysqli　の;は外しております。
　＊phpinfo()のphpファイル(www/test.php)にアクセスする際、
　　　　XAMPPからApacheとMySQLをスタートさせてアクセスすると、Not Found　エラーになるのですが、コマンドからphp- S localhost:8080　をスタートさせてアクセスすると、↑に添付したphpinfoがきちんと表示されます

以上の情報から、考えられる解決方法はありますでしょうか。

質問にあたりどのような情報が必要かがわからなかったので、わかっている範囲で詳しく書いたつもりなのですが
もし追加で必要な情報があればご指摘いただければ確認させていただきます。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

---

コメントいただいた、

```
C:\Users\USER>php -c C:/php7/php.ini -m
```

をコマンド実行した結果はこちらです。

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mysqlnd
pcre
PDO
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Comment: iniを読み込んでいなければ、当たり前ですがmysqliは入っていないでしょう。問題点としては何かの理由でapacheがstartできないことでしょう。phpをコマンドラインで実行するとどうなりますか？コンソールから`php -c C:/php7/php.ini -m`

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。現在Apacheはスタートできます。（質問の補足情報に書いた通り、数日前にポートを8080に変更するなどを行い、動くようになりました。ただその際に"PHPIniDir "C:/php7"の記述をphp.iniから消しています。そしてもしそれを再記入すると、Apacheがまたstartできなくなってしまいます・・。）　//　コマンド実行した結果、こちらです。何かお判りでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。https://gyazo.com/ba8cb7b8156446a39b766700a72ae6db

Comment: XAMPP を利用しているなら PHP も XAMPP のインストールディレクトリ以下に含まれるはずで、これとは別に `C:\php7` が出てくるのはなぜでしょう？個別にも PHP をインストールしているのでしょうか？ / 状況を整理するためにも、不要なものは一旦アンインストールしてから設定を改めて行ってみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: XAMPPをインストールして数日後に、別にPHPをインストールしました。その際に参考にしていたサイトの手順通りに進まず、一旦”PHP”で検索してでてきたフォルダを削除してから再インストールを行ったので、XAMPPの中にあったPHPフォルダは既に消してしまっていると思います。（xamppフォルダの中にないです)　今、PHP7をxamppフォルダの中に配置してパスなどの再設定を行いましたが、やはりphp.iniは"no value"のままです。PHPは個別にインストールする必要なかったんですね。なんだか複雑になってしまっておりますが、XAMPPのコントロールパネルのApacheのConfigのphp.iniをクリックすると、「The system cannot find the path specified」と出るため、やはりphp.iniの設定がおかしいんだと思います。。

Comment: インストールの手順中に何らかの設定ミスをした可能性がありますね。インストール時に行って手順をすべて記述してもらって問題を洗い出すか、別の方がお話している通りすべてアンインストールしてやり直したほうがよいでしょう。

Comment: アンインストールしてやり直すことにします。皆さん、考えてくださりありがとうございました。

Comment: 追記：すべて正常に動作するようになりました。^^（個別にインストールしてしまっていたPHPと、xamppをアンインストールして、xamppを再インストールしました）